# Malloc in openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl, malloc, aes, free

I got a problem when I encrypt a data with aes encryption.
this is the source code:

```
    std::string aes_encrypt( std::string text, std::string password ){
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ectx;
    std::string key = sha256(password);
    std::string iv = sha256("aes_iv_"+password);
    int size = text.size();
    unsigned char* out = (unsigned char*)malloc( size );
    int outlen = 0;
    int tlen = 0;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init( &ectx );
    EVP_EncryptInit( &ectx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), (const unsigned char*)key.c_str(), (const unsigned char*)iv.c_str() );
    EVP_EncryptUpdate( &ectx, out, &outlen, (const unsigned char*)text.c_str(), text.size() );
    tlen += outlen;
    EVP_EncryptFinal( &ectx, out+tlen, &outlen );
    tlen += outlen;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup( &ectx );

    std::string data( (const char*)out, tlen );
    free( out );
    return data;
}
```

My application will crash in this line: free(out);
Any solution to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to check the return value of `malloc`. If it is NULL, the allocation failed. Also, you don't need to cast the result.

Comment: also, you're going to store the encrypted result in a `std::string`? What happens if there is a NULL byte in the middle of your encrypted buffer? I'm not sure but I think the constructor will stop copying bytes at that point.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, this is C++, I thought you _did_ need to cast in that case. I know it's ill-advised in C.

Comment: @paxdiablo Ah you could be right. Dammit, and I just *stopped* casting it!

Answer (score 1):

In the line "out = (unsigned char*) malloc(size)" you assume the output will never be longer than the input. This is NOT the case (openssl documentation says you have to add something like a block size or so), thus I believe you have a buffer overflow in the malloc'ed  buffer during the encryption, which causes a crash during the free(...) call --- that's quite usual thing when you destroy malloc/free data structures by overflowing an malloc'ated buffer.

Comment: OpenSSL is indeed very tricky with what it does with this buffer. Over-allocation is recommended. For my case, even double the length wasn't enough!